# LaTex for home use

Tags: math-software

I would like to have a program similar to this website that allows me to write math equations.  Is there a good program that is easy to use.  I tried the LaTex add in for Google docs, but it is not that good.  It was simple to install, but I am not the excite about using it.  The output is inconsistent and blurry.  Is there anything else out there that is easy to use and has good output?  I was looking for something free.

I really would like to take notes on my computer for precalculus and calculus.  I'd like to be able to write equations in my notes.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.latex-project.org/) and [this](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) may help.

Comment: Overleaf is always a good free option. Less finely customizable-- but you don't need that anyways. It's free, autofills, and cloud saves!

Comment: You'll also find some pointers in the questions listed under *Related* on the right-hand side.

Comment: The editor on this website basically implements markdown with mathjax support. There are a bunch of in-browser markdown editors that have similar features, and would be a close analogue of this experience. I tend to use stackedit.io which has most (but not all) of the maths typesetting features of the MSE editor. Note, btw, that while such tools are fine for short notes, if you're writing long documents or articles, you'd be better off using a full-on Latex editor (overleaf is a good online one, but of course you can also locally install something on your machine).

Comment: Overleaf is incredible.  Thank you , the install of LaTex was too much for me.

Answer (score 3):

As Marty Cohen mentioned, the Markdown format is really handy!

I use an app called [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/)- once you've downloaded it you can install a [community plugin](https://obsidian.md/plugins?id=obsidian-git) to have your notes sync automatically to a GitHub repo (you can keep it private). This way all of your notes are synced across your devices.

You can insert $LaTeX$ equations by surrounding your code in dollar symbols `$/eqn$`, and it renders live. CodeCogs offers a [simple tool](https://latex.codecogs.com/eqneditor/editor.php) to generate equations using a GUI whose code you can then copy/paste into the Markdown file.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac,
MacDown is great
(IMHO).

You can download it at
https://macdown.uranusjr.com/

It has two columns, one with your MathJax
and one with the formatted equations and text.

I use it all the time
for my submissions here.
I format them in MacDown
and then copy and paste
the MathJax into the answer or question area.

I save the .md files
so I can refer to or modify them later.

Answer (score 0):

[StackEdit (stackedit.io)](https://stackedit.io) is a nice Markdown + KaTeX editor in the browser for writing documents exactly as you would a Stack answer. I think documents are saved in local storage, so might not be ideal for use across multiple devices (haven't tested it), but it's convenient to draw up a quick document with math and save as a PDF.

It's very similar to MacDown and Obsidian recommended in the other answer, but run in-browser rather than locally.